# why thumbnail are not displayed in img tag using the values() method in views?

Tags: django

I have a model with 10 fields. But in the template I just want to return four fields('slug', 'code', 'area', 'thumbnail') . To do this, I used the Values() in View. But the thumbnail is not displayed in img tag of template and the src of the photo is empty.
views.py:

```
def home(request):
allVilla = Villa.objects.filter(status='p').values('slug', 'code', 'area', 'thumbnail')[:8]
context = {
    'allvilla': allVilla,
    'allproduct': allproduct,
}
return render(request, "wooden/home.html", context)
```

home.html (template):

```
<div id="slider_villa_home" class="owl-carousel owl-theme box_slider_villa dir_left">
           
            {% for v in allvilla %}
            <div class="item position-relative box_item wow flipInY">
                <div class="position-absolute bg"></div>
                <img class="img_item" src="{{ v.thumbnail.url }}" alt="{{ v.code }}">
                <p class="position-absolute p_item">
                    <b>{{ v.code }}</b>
                    <br>
                    <b>{{ v.area }}</b>
                </p>
                <a class="position-absolute link_item" href="{% url 'wooden:singlevilla' v.slug %}">
                    </a>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
```

[image]

pls help

Comment: Because `.values` returns only a dictionary, hence you can not call `.url` on the `thumbnail`, since that is no longer a `FieldFile`.

Comment: This is one (of the many) reasons *not* to use `.values()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [**`.values(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#only), then Django will return a collection of *dictionaries*. This thus means that the logical layer of the model (and its fields) no longer works, hence `v.thumbnail.url` makes no sense, since `v.thumbnail` is a simple string, and thus no longer a `FieldFile` that has a `.url` attribute.

You better load model objects, and work with these objects, so:

```
def home(request):
    #                            no .values() ↓
    allVilla = Villa.objects.filter(status='p')[:8]
    context = {
        'allvilla': allVilla,
        'allproduct': allproduct,
    }
    return render(request, "wooden/home.html", context)
```

If you want to minimize bandwitdth to only return a subset of the columns, you can work with [**`.only(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#only):

```
def home(request):
    allVilla = Villa.objects.filter(
        status='p'    # using only ↓
    ).only('pk', 'slug', 'code', 'area', 'thumbnail')[:8]
    context = {
        'allvilla': allVilla,
        'allproduct': allproduct,
    }
    return render(request, "wooden/home.html", context)
```